# Spans acting up in fluid row

Tags: html, css

This is a Wordpress site I'm working on. The Contact Form is using Contact Form 7.

The reason I am not posting in WordPress is because it has nothing to do with it.

I created part of the form and it was working fine. Then all the sudden the spans in this new row start over lapping. I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Here is a link to the form code https://jsfiddle.net/pk72mzfk/

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <p class="span6 field">
        <label for "one">Business Legal Name:</label>
        <br/>[text* business-legal-name id:one]</p>
    <p class="span6 field">
        <label for "two">Business DBA Name:</label>
        <br/>[text* business-dba-name id:two]</p>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <p class="span3 field">
        <label for "three">Type of Business Entity (Check One):</label>
        <br/>[checkbox* biz-entity id:three label_first "Corporation" "LLC" "Partnership Ltd." "Partnership" "LLP" "Sole Proprietor"]</p>
    <p class="span3 field">
        <label for "four">Primary Business Structure (Check All That Apply):</label>
        <br/>[checkbox* biz-structure id:four label_first "Home Based Business" "Franchise" "E-Commerce" "None Of The Above"]</p>
    <p class="span3 field">
        <label for "five">Does the Merchant have any open MCA or loan accounts? (Check One):</label>
        <br/>[checkbox* open-mca-loan id:five label_first "Yes" "No"]</p>
    <p class="span3 field">
        <label for "six">Federal Tax ID:</label>
        <br/>[text* federal-tax-id id:six]</p>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <p class="span2 field">
        <label for "seven">Industry Type (Describe):</label>
        <br/>[text* industry-type id:seven]</p>
    <p class="span2 field">
        <label for "eight">Current Credit Card Processor:</label>
        <br/>[text* ccc-processor id:eight]</p>
    <p class="span2 field">
        <label for "nine">State of Incorporation:</label>
        <br/>[text* state-of-incorp id:nine]</p>
    <p class="span2 field">
        <label for "ten">Use of Proceeds:</label>
        <br/>[text* use-of-proceed id:ten]</p>
    <p class="span2 field">
        <label for "eleven">Business start date under current Ownership:</label>
        <br/>[date* date-44 id:eleven]</p>
    <p class="span2 field">
        <label for "twelve">Merchant Email Address:</label>
        <br/>[email* merchant-email id:twelve]</p>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <p class="span6 field">
        <label for "thirteen">Physical Street Address:</label>
        <br/>[text* phys-street-address id:thirteen]</p>
    <p class="span1 field">
        <label for "fourteen">City:</label>
        <br/>[text* city-psa id:fourteen]</p>
    <p class="span1 field">
        <label for "fifteen">State:</label>
        <br/>[text* state-psa id:fifteen]</p>
    <p class="span1 field">
        <label for "sixteen">Zip Code:</label>
        <br/>[text* zip-psa id:sixteen]</p>
    <p class="span2 field">
        <label for "seventeen">Physical Location Phone:</label>
        <br/>[tel* tel-psa id:seventeen]</p>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <p class="span6 field">
        <label for "eighteen">Billing Street Address (If different than above):</label>
        <br/>[text billing-address id:eighteen]</p>
    <p class="span1 field">
        <label for "nineteen">City:</label>
        <br/>[text city-bsa id:nineteen]</p>
    <p class="span1 field">
        <label for "twenty">State:</label>
        <br/>[text state-bsa id:twenty]</p>
    <p class="span1 field">
        <label for "twentyone">Zip Code:</label>
        <br/>[text zip-bsa id:twentyone]</p>
    <p class="span2 field">
        <label for "twentytwo">Physical Location Phone:</label>
        <br/>[tel tel-bsa id:twentytwo]</p>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <p class="span1" field></p>
    <p class="span2" field>
        <label for "twentythree">Preferred Contact Phone #:</label>
        <br/>[tel* preferred-phone id:twentythree]</p>
    <p class="span2" field>
        <label for "twentyfour">Business Location(s):</label>
        <br/>[checkbox* biz-location id:twentyfour label_first "Rented" "Mortgaged"]
        <br/>
        <label for "twentyfive">Monthly Payment</label>
        <br/>[text* monthly-payment id:twentyfive]</p>
    <p class="span2" field>
        <label for "twentysix">Avg. Monthly Credit Card Volume:</label>
        <br/>[text* monthly-cc-volume id:twentysix]</p>
    <p class="span2" field>
        <label for "twentyseven">Avg. Transaction Amount:</label>
        <br/>[text* avg-transaction id:twentyseven]</p>
    <p class="span2" field>
        <label for "twentyeight">Gross Annual Sales (from previous year's tax return):</label>
        <br/>[text* gross-annual id:twentyeight]</p>
    <p class="span1" field></p>
</div>
```

here is a link to the page the form is on https://flashcapitalfunding.com/application/

you can see my code is correct and other rows are working fine. ( as far as I kow/can see)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you've got 2 extra `span`'s in that row. Also seems there's too many fields to fit on that same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of your classes, for example `<p class="span1" field></p>` should be `<p class="span1 field"></p>` and `<p class="span2" field>` should be `<p class="span2 field">`